# hasNextInt() From Scanner behaving weirdly

Tags: java, user-input, java.util.scanner

I have a very simple loop that waits for a number (int) and as long as that number is not `exitOption` it does not leave the loop, however I get an unexpected error, and I don't know what's causing it.

**Edit**

Adding another snippet so you can compile

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws   FileNotFoundException,
                                                SecurityException,
                                                IOException,
                                                ClassNotFoundException {


    while (controller.selectOptionMM());
```

**/Edit**

```
public boolean selectOptionMM() throws  SecurityException, 
                                        FileNotFoundException, 
                                        IOException {

    int cmd = ui.getExitOption();

    ui.mainMenu();
    cmd = utils.readInteger(">>> "); // this is my problem, right here
                                     // code in next snippet 
    while (cmd <1 || cmd > ui.getExitOption()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid command!");
        cmd = utils.readInteger(">>> ");
    }

    switch (cmd) {
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
    case 3: 
    case 4: this.repository.close();
            return true;
    case 5: return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is what fails:

```
public int readInteger(String cmdPrompt) {
    int cmd = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf(cmdPrompt);
    try {
        if (input.hasNextInt()) 
            cmd = input.nextInt(); // first time it works
            // Second time it does not allow me to input anything
                            // catches InputMissmatchException, does not print message
                            // for said catch
                            // infinitely prints "Invalid command" from previous snippet

    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println("InputMismatchException: " + ime);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchElementException: " + nsee);
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {

    } finally {
        input.close(); // not sure if I should test with if (input != null) THEN close
    }


    return cmd;
}
```

**First time** I pass trough, it reads the number no problem. Now if the number is not 5 (in this case exitOption), it passes again trough `readInteger(String cmdPrompt)` except this time it jumps to `catch (InputMismatchException ime)` (debug) except it does not print that message and just jumps to `Error, input must be number` and `Invalid command`.

**Is something stuck in my input buffer, can I flush it, why is it (input buffer) stuck (with random data)???**

I'll try debugging again and see what's stuck in my input buffer, if I can figure out how to see that.

Comment: Your first and second snippets of code don't seem at all related to one another unless I am missing something obvious...

Comment: First one is used as a loop (as in only exits when returns false), posted it just in case. It calls a function (the second snippet).

Comment: If you're catching the exceptions, you don't need to declare them as thrown in the method signature.

Comment: What exactly is your input. (What exactly o our read from `System.in`)

Comment: I read numbers between 1 and exitOption (for now 5). Anything higher or lower is not a valid command. I test by inputting 1 and I get an endless stram of "invalid command".

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but the call to input.close() will close the underlying input stream - in this case, System.in. Not sure what happens when you close System.in, but it's probably best to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Alex indeed, that was it, post it as an answer and I'll accept it, thank you !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the call to `input.close()` - this causes the underlying input stream to be closed. When the input stream being closed is `System.in`, bad things happen (namely, you can't read from stdin any more). You should be OK just eliminating this line.

Comment: Just to let you know. His base question was different.

Answer (score 1):

```
     input.hasNextInt()
```

This line throws the exception if there is no Integer, so instead of it going to else block it forward to catch block. It will never go to else block if exception get caught.

Comment: So are you saying I shouldn't catch the exception. I used similar code with no exceptions and it worked. I am a bit confused though

Comment: No you should definitely catch exception. The thing is if exception get caught then `if` condition never evaluates either its true or false.

Comment: What would you recommend then ? What's a safe way of reading an integer, should I read a line and `parseInt` ?

Comment: if your final aim is to print this line `System.out.println("Error, input must be number");` then put it in `finally` block. It will always get executed or you can put them in `catch` block. Depends what you prefer. I will prefer to put in `catch` block,

Comment: Deleted the else block. Now I input 1, and it infinitely prints `Invalid command`. How does the input stream get clogged ? I don't see the connection between what you're saying and what I'm saying.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? I didnt understand your question :-(

Comment: I have a program, with several options, I select this options with numbers (1) add, 2) delete, what ever). I am trying to keep reading numbers, handling the options, until I hit `exitOption` when I exit the loop (first code snippet returns false). Instead I input 1, call `readInteger()` and get an endless stream of `Invalid command`

Comment: Don't modify and edit base question. If you stuck somewhere else then ask new question in SO. If you keep doing that then question and answer won't make any sense to potential readers.